# Undefined name '_selectedIndex'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: android, reactjs, flutter, mobile

I have a problem regarding my flutter code, I did not find or the setState in this code is not defined, I want to navigate it to the "**nilai**" page it is correct, but the navbar doesn't shift or even opens a new page, namely **nilai.dart**

This is the **home.dart** code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'nilai.dart';
import 'evaluasi.dart';
import 'profil.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomeScreen(),
    NilaiScreen(),
    EvaluasiBelajarScreen(),
    ProfilScreen(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: _widgetOptions,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.rocket_launch),
            label: 'Nilai',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.assignment),
            label: 'Evaluasi',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profil',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> imageList = [
    'assets/images/gambar1.jpg',
    'assets/images/gambar2.jpg',
    'assets/images/gambar3.jpg',
  ];

  final List<String> subjects = [
    'Matematika',
    'Bahasa Inggris',
    'IPA',
    'IPS',
    'Olahraga',
    'Seni Budaya',
    'PPKn',
    'Agama',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 60.0,
              left: 24.0,
            ),
            child: Text(
              'Selamat Datang',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
            child: Text(
              'Bagus Lindu!',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
              overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 200.0,
              autoPlay: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
            ),
            items: imageList.map((item) {
              return Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        item,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
            child: Text(
              'Pilih Mata Pelajaran:',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: subjects.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 24.0, right: 24.0, top: 2.0, bottom: 5.0),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 0.5,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                    title: Text(subjects[index]),
                    trailing: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedIndex = 1; // Mengatur indeks tab "Nilai"
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text('Lihat Detail Nilai'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting the "**Lihat Detail Nilai**" section if clicked it would open the **nilai.dart** with a navbar that slides to the **nilai** ​​section. Instead of opening the values ​​tab.

Comment: You defined _selectedIndex in HomePage class so you can not access it in HomeScreen.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass _selectedIndex to each widget that would want to use it.

```
HomeScreen(_selectedIndex)
```

How HomeScreen will access it

```
widget HomeScreen extends ... {
 var _selectedIndex;

 HomeScreen(this._selectedIndex);

 Widget Build()... {
  ...
  // then you can use your onPressed as it is
 }     

}
```

A safer way rather than passing the variable   around, you should pass a VoidCallback around. In this case the onItemTapped you have should be passed to each widget that needs it, for example.

```
HomeScreen(onItemTapped: onItemTapped);
```

To define in widget

```
widget HomeScreen extends ... {
 VoidCallback onItemTapped

 HomeScreen({ required this.onItemTapped });

 Widget Build()... {
  ...
  onPressed: () => onItemTapped,
 }     

}
```